# Custom HTML Select creation

Tags: html, select, user-interface, input, twitter-bootstrap

I'm starting to use **Bootstrap from Twitter** and needed to add an **HTML Select** to my document.
I've found a great implementation of a HTML Select in this Demo http://rails-admin-tb.herokuapp.com/admin/drafts/new and was looking to create something similar.

Do you know if there is already an UI element that I can include to get the same look and behavior?
If not, how can I create something similar?

All that site has a great look, and I was hoping if someone could give me some hints on how to achieve a look and feel like that.

Comment: Any code draft? An autocomplete on an Html Select seems weird.

Comment: @Fredy31 You can see a sample on the demo that I added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no HTML element that can do this natively (yet), it must be done with javascript.

Try "Chosen": http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: Hey, nice one @Madmartigan! "Chosen" seems to solve most of my needs and it looks great!

Answer (score 1):

There's jQuery UI, which is great and really comprehensive with great different looks and stylings too, check it out on their [homepage](http://jqueryui.com/).

Great for styles like that is the [jQuery Toolbox](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html) coming with great effects out of the box.

All in all jQuery is a great framework for achieving stuff like that, has the biggest js-framework community and is probably the future of the web! There are many other frameworks out there too, but it's always javascript if you want a nice solution with effects.

Comment: Thanks Dan. jQuery tools has some nice widgets, but it has nothing to enhance an HTML select, or have I missed it?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you want. You could use a slider for numeric values and it also supports html5 date input. It doesn't natively has autocomplete but togeter with your own js autocomplete plugin you could extend it with the nice jquery tools skinning! see the [forms toolbox](http://flowplayer.org/tools/release-notes/index.html#form)

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://silviomoreto.github.com/bootstrap-select/

it maintains the appearance of the bootstrap using the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give an update on the available options, more recently I've also been using **[Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/)**, which is based on Chosen and has a lot of nice features.
The source code is also available on https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2 .